# iOS SwiftUI change default Font for every View

Tags: swift, text, fonts, swiftui, ios13

I'm trying to change the **default font** in **SwiftUI** for every view in my app.

**What I want to avoid is** to set it every time like so:

```
.font(.custom("FONT_NAME", size: 20))
```

**What I want is** to change it just one time for all Text views, and most important, I would like to keep using the modifiers:

```
.font(.caption)
```

without resetting the Text view to the system font.

But still I didn't find any solution, does anyone have one?

Answer (score 5):

You can build your own view modifier. You can define what size and font you want to use for each of the UIFont.TextStyle inside `private var fontDescriptions:`.

Now you can call this modifier on you Views like this. `Text("my text").customFont(.headline)`

Keep in mind, this one also implements the font scaling feature.

You could also call your "customFont" function "font" if you want to be hardcore.

```
extension View {
    func customFont(_ textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle) -> ModifiedContent<Self, CustomFont> {
        return modifier(CustomFont(textStyle: textStyle))
    }
}

struct CustomFont: ViewModifier {
    let textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle

    /// Will trigger the refresh of the view when the ContentSizeCategory changes.
    @Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory: ContentSizeCategory

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {

        guard let fontDescription = fontDescriptions[textStyle] else {

            print("textStyle nicht vorhanden: \(textStyle)")

            return content.font(.system(.body));
        }

        let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: textStyle)
        let fontSize = fontMetrics.scaledValue(for: fontDescription.1)

        return content.font(.custom(fontDescription.0, size: fontSize))
    }
}

/// Define the custom fonts to use, depending on the TextStyle.
typealias CustomFontDescription = (String, CGFloat)
private var fontDescriptions: [UIFont.TextStyle: CustomFontDescription] = [
    .headline: ("MYFONT", SIZE),
    .subheadline: ("MYFONT", SIZE),
    ...
]
```

Comment: I spent all day searching for a solution that would dynamically scale fonts as you change them and not just set them on load. This was the only solution that worked for me. Well done!

Comment: Did you mean to use `Font.custom(_ name:, fixedSize:)`? because `custom(_ name: , size:)` scales text automatically with body size.
In iOS 14 there is a method `custom(_ name:size:relativeTo textStyle:) -> Font`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view modifier to solve your case.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct CustomText: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(.custom("FONT_NAME", size: textSize(textStyle: .headline)))
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
           //Other customization
    }
}
//For Accessibility feature
func textSize(textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle) -> CGFloat {
   return UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle).pointSize
}
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, SwiftUI")
            .modifier(CustomText())
            .font(.caption) // You can still change the font .
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This one is lacking the accessibility features for text. I thing merging our both answers is the right answer.  Mine for overriding .font(.caption) and yours for setting the default font via body modifier.

Comment: I have updated my answer to support accessibility feature @Mamaessen